What is a Very Frighteningly Dangerous Word™?
This puzzle is based off and inspired by the What is a Word™ series started by JLee.

The puzzle:
If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Very Frighteningly Dangerous Word.
Here is a list of examples:



Very Frighteningly Dangerous Words™
Non-Very-Frighteningly-Dangerous Words™




Bad
Awful


Reptile
Lizard


Wide
Large


Miserable
Dreary


Austere
Strict


Ersatz
Substitute


Vile
Foul


Hostile
Unfriendly


Carnivorous
Meat-Eating


Slippery
Slick


Grim
Uninviting


Penultimate
Second-to-Last



Blank



In CSV format:
Very Frighteningly Dangerous Words™,Non-Very-Frighteningly-Dangerous Words™
Bad,Awful
Reptile,Lizard
Wide,Large
Miserable,Dreary
Austere,Strict
Ersatz,Substitute
Vile,Foul
Hostile,Unfriendly
Carnivorous,Meat-Eating
Slippery,Slick
Grim,Uninviting
Penultimate,Second-to-Last
,Blank

What is the rule to tell whether a word is a Very Frighteningly Dangerous Word™ or not? Why is it called a Very Frighteningly Dangerous Word™?

Very Frighteningly Dangerous words are those that

 are in the title of a novel in the A Series of Unfortunate Events series.

"Very Frighteningly Dangerous" may be a reference to

 the acronym V.F.D., an organization in the series.


Specifically, rot13(gur gvgyrf nyy unir gur sbez "Gur  " naq gur ISQ jbeqf ner nyy gur nqwrpgvirf. Gur guvegrragu obbx oernxf gur cnggrea naq vf whfg pnyyrq "Gur Raq", urapr gur zvffvat ragel va gur gnoyr.)
